# how to tune jvm when using spring boot application as unix service

Tags: performance, service, jvm, spring-boot, init.d

i'm using the new spring-boot 1.3.0 feature to run tomcat embedded spring-boot application jar as a unix service.

All is working fine but i don't know how to tune jvm (with -Xms and -Xmx parameters for example)

I've searched in spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-initd-service) and around the web without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's missing from the documentation (I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3808) to correct that), but you should be able to use the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.

You can configure it in a `.conf` file that's situated next to the jar. For example, if you jar file is `/var/myapp/myapp.jar`, the file `/var/myapp/myapp.conf` will be sourced by the launch script.

Comment: i've read that service strips all environment variables but TERM, PATH and LANG. So how can it work ?

Comment: You can use a `.conf` file situated next to your jar. I've updated my answer with the details.

Comment: thanks for you response. it works  :-) just a misspelling :
"the file /var/myapp/myapp.conf will be sourced by the launch script."

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option to achieve the same , if you are running jar with mvn you can do something like this

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xmx512m"`

And If you are running with java -jar ,you can  try something like this

`java -Xmx1G -jar myapp.jar`